# Get BulkCopy Percentage for Progress Bar

Tags: c#, datatable, progress-bar, sqlbulkcopy

I am using normal `INSERT` queries to write a `DataTable` into my database. This way I know which record is being inserted and I can tell my `ProgressBar` to show the progress percentage correctly. But I would like to replace my record-by-record INSERTs with one bulk copy because it is apparently much faster. 
When I look at the bulk copy code, the main copy part is done via the function
`WriteToServer()`. I was wondering if there is a way to notify my progress bar about the percentage. I do not need to now the percentage when every record is being inserted. I have set my program to show progress by each 500 records. I would like my progress bar to still be able to show the percentage and not a simple marquee that says "in progress...". Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use [`NotifyAfter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.notifyafter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: In addition to @MatthewWatson answer you should subscribe to [SqlRowsCopied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied.aspx) event to get notified how much rows was proccessed at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need progressbar with SQLBulkcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131088/i-need-progressbar-with-sqlbulkcopy)