# I need progressbar with SQLBulkcopy

Tags: c#, progress-bar, sqlbulkcopy

I need progress bar for my application. I am uploading data through text file into SQL Server but it takes a lot of time and also i used background worker for the same but that's not working properly so i just need to know is there any way i can use progress  bar with SQL Bulk Copy and it tells me that's 2000 records inserted? 
Here is my code:

```
 public void bulkinsert(string tablename, DataTable dt)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlBulkCopy blkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        blkcopy.DestinationTableName = tablename;
        blkcopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
        blkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1500;
        blkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        blkcopy.Close();

    }
```

I really appreciate your responses.

Comment: I'd recommend using a loading wheel in this case, maybe with a timer, letting the user know it's doing something. Otherwise the accuracy of the progress bar would be horrible and the user would definitely think something is wrong if it gets stuck at 99%. <-Microsoft used to do this alllll the time.

Comment: Use the NotifyAfter property of the SqlBulkCopy class to specify a notification threshold and catch the SqlRowsCopied event to update your progressbar. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the [SqlBulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied(v=vs.110).aspx) event which

> Occurs every time that the number of rows specified by the NotifyAfter
>   property have been processed.

I would also use Async Await and use a [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of a background worker

Comment: Thanks! @Conrad Frix .. It really helps and my application is running fine and now i can see records being processed over time. I just have a small question for you that did it slow the process when we use notify after property ?

Comment: Well you can use `System.Diagonistcs.Stopwatch` and test it both with and without handling SqlRowsCopied and see what the difference is. If there is a difference you can ask your users if it's worth having the progress bar

Comment: Yes i checked with the Stop Watch... it was 2 to 3 minutes delay in the process but i guess that's negligible so any ways thanks for the help man!